# ajax to get html page from spring boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I am trying to get html page from spring boot using jquery ajax.

This is my ajax call

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url:"myurl",
        type:"get",
        dataType: "html",
        data:formData
    });

    jqxhr.done(function( data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

        //here i get data is not defined, textStatus not defined ??

    });
```

And this is my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/myurl", produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public ModelAndView  getMyHtml(  Input input, HttpServletRequest request ) throws Exception  {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("myPage");
//my business logic code goes here
return model;
}
```

`myPage` is html page that uses thymeleaf and renders page.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Why do you want to call java controller to read a HTML file? You can directly fire ajax to read the html file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this ? thank you

Comment: You could replace the done-function by a success- and a error-function to improve debuging. Without further information it isn't possible to see why it is going wrong.